# How to increase App Engine Conversion service quota limit with billing enabled

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

Apparently [Conversion service quota](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=pl-PL#Conversion) limit is 100 conversions a day whenever you have billing enabled or not.

1. How to increase this quota?
2. How to check current quota usage for Conversion service?

Answer (score 1):

You can [request an increase](http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?&contact_type=AppEngineCPURequest) from Google